# CVXPY variance minimization problem solver error

Tags: python, optimization, cvxpy

I am trying to solve a MIP with cvxpy to optimize a grouping problem (partition a set of students in classes while minimizing the variance of age among the students in a class.) but I can get it to work as long as I don't add a variance calculation to the objective function.

So far I have set up the problem with following version of cvxpy (I also use pandas for input and ouput of problem data from and to file and numpy for matrix/vector manipulation)

```
cvxopt==1.3.0
cvxpy==1.2.2
numpy==1.22.0
pandas==1.5.2
```

This is my import block, with the alias given to different modules

`import pandas as pd import numpy as np import cvxpy as cp`

I then defined mean and variance functions, as found in a blog post for cvxpy

```
def mean(x):
    return cp.sum(x) / x.size

def variance(X:cp.Variable, mode='unbiased'):
    if mode == 'unbiased':
        scale = X.size - 1
    elif mode == 'mle':
        scale = X.size
    else:
        raise ValueError('unknown mode: ' + str(mode))
    return cp.sum_squares(X - mean(X)) / scale
```

And based on the above an "age_cost" function to define a component of the objective function that should be minimized, where X is a cvxpy binary variable defined as a matrix with dimensions (number_of_students,available_lessons_number)

```
def age_cost(df:pd.DataFrame,X:cp.Variable):
    cost=0
    for i,age in df.Age.items():
        cost+=variance(X[:][i]*age)
    return cost
```

I then defined the other component of the objective function to assign to classes the highest possible number of students

```
objective_component1=students_num-assigned @ np.ones(DAYS*SLOTS) @ np.ones(students_num)
```

And defined the objective as :

```
objective_component2=age_cost(my_data,assigned)
objective=cp.Minimize(objective_component1+objective_component2)
```

If I then set the problem (I don't think constraints are part of the issue, so I didn't put them in this question) and try to solve it:

```
problem1=cp.Problem(objective,constraints)
problem1.solve(verbose=True)
```

This is what I get on terminal:

```
===============================================================================
                                     CVXPY                                     
                                     v1.2.2                                    
===============================================================================
(CVXPY) Jan 04 03:09:59 PM: Your problem has 4550 variables, 3382 constraints, and 0 parameters.
(CVXPY) Jan 04 03:10:01 PM: It is compliant with the following grammars: DCP, DQCP
(CVXPY) Jan 04 03:10:01 PM: (If you need to solve this problem multiple times, but with different data, consider using parameters.)
(CVXPY) Jan 04 03:10:01 PM: CVXPY will first compile your problem; then, it will invoke a numerical solver to obtain a solution.
...
<error stack omitted>
...

Either candidate conic solvers (['GLPK_MI']) do not support the cones output by the problem (SOC, NonNeg, Zero), or there are not enough constraints in the problem.
```

If I remove the "age_cost" constraint and redefine the objective as:

`objective=cp.Minimize(objective_component1)`

Then I obtain a correct solution (with regard to my contraints) and the following output:

```
===============================================================================
                                     CVXPY                                     
                                     v1.2.2                                    
===============================================================================
(CVXPY) Jan 04 03:15:24 PM: Your problem has 4550 variables, 3382 constraints, and 0 parameters.
(CVXPY) Jan 04 03:15:26 PM: It is compliant with the following grammars: DCP, DQCP
(CVXPY) Jan 04 03:15:26 PM: (If you need to solve this problem multiple times, but with different data, consider using parameters.)
(CVXPY) Jan 04 03:15:26 PM: CVXPY will first compile your problem; then, it will invoke a numerical solver to obtain a solution.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                  Compilation                                  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(CVXPY) Jan 04 03:15:29 PM: Compiling problem (target solver=GLPK_MI).
(CVXPY) Jan 04 03:15:29 PM: Reduction chain: Dcp2Cone -> CvxAttr2Constr -> ConeMatrixStuffing -> GLPK_MI
(CVXPY) Jan 04 03:15:29 PM: Applying reduction Dcp2Cone
(CVXPY) Jan 04 03:15:31 PM: Applying reduction CvxAttr2Constr
(CVXPY) Jan 04 03:15:31 PM: Applying reduction ConeMatrixStuffing
(CVXPY) Jan 04 03:15:39 PM: Applying reduction GLPK_MI
(CVXPY) Jan 04 03:15:47 PM: Finished problem compilation (took 2.111e+01 seconds).
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                Numerical solver                               
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(CVXPY) Jan 04 03:15:47 PM: Invoking solver GLPK_MI  to obtain a solution.
      0: obj =  -8.800000000e+01 inf =   7.500e+01 (46)
     68: obj =  -8.800000000e+01 inf =   0.000e+00 (0)
+    68: mip =     not found yet >=              -inf        (1; 0)
+    68: >>>>>  -8.800000000e+01 >=  -8.800000000e+01   0.0% (1; 0)
+    68: mip =  -8.800000000e+01 >=     tree is empty   0.0% (0; 1)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                    Summary                                    
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(CVXPY) Jan 04 03:15:47 PM: Problem status: optimal
(CVXPY) Jan 04 03:15:47 PM: Optimal value: -3.800e+01
(CVXPY) Jan 04 03:15:47 PM: Compilation took 2.111e+01 seconds
(CVXPY) Jan 04 03:15:47 PM: Solver (including time spent in interface) took 1.334e-01 seconds
```

Am I using the wrong solver? If a solver was wrong for the class of my problem how can I understand which solver is feasible for my problem definition? The "compliant with DCP grammar" message I get in the output of the problem means that the problem is well formed ?

Comment: I think you don't have access to an MIQP  solver.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen thanks for the answer, I found a cvxpy example at https://www.cvxpy.org/examples/basic/mixed_integer_quadratic_program.html that solved an miqp without specifying a solver when calling `.solve()`, so shouldn't the default solver work?

Comment: Hi Erwin, if you care for it you could answer instead of commenting so I can choose your answer because it was as you said. I installed SCIP solver and now I don't get that error anymore, even without explicitly saying which solver I want to use (i can see in the logs cvxpy is using SCIP).